# Does Lyapunov stability imply that the Lyapunov function is monotonically decreasing?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, lyapunov-functions

Suppose we have a system $$\dot x = Ax$$

And a Lyapunov function $$V (x(t)) \geq 0, \forall t $$

My question is, does the fact $\dot V(x) = \nabla V(x)^\top \dot x < 0$ imply that $V(x(t))$ is monotonically decreasing along with time?

Ok, so intuitively, integrating bothsides we have $V(x(t)) < V(x(0))$, $\forall t$.

So it is decreasing relative to the initial time.

But what about the time afterwards, can we guarantee

$V(x(t_2)) < V(x(t_1)) $ where $t_2>t_1>0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $V(x(t))$ decreases with increasing $t$ along any trajectory $x(t)$, strictly monotonically in fact.

For if

$t_2 > t_1 \tag 1$

we have

$V(x(t_2)) - V(x(t_1))$
$= \displaystyle \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \dot V(x(s)) \; ds = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \nabla V(x(s))^T \dot x(s) \; ds  < 0, \tag 2$

since the integrand

$\nabla V(x(s))^T \dot x(s) < 0 \tag 3$

everywhere; thus

$V(x(t_2)) < V(x(t_1)) \tag 4$

along $x(t)$ whenever (1) binds.